# PHP MYSQL Javascript playing audio each time someone INSERT INTO database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

is there anyway to playing mp3 audio each time someone INSERT INTO to database?

can javascript handling this kind app?

Comment: Do you want this played on the client or at the server?

Comment: i want it play into only for my server? so, i know that someone just making interaction on my website. is that really possible Mr. RiggsFolly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need javascript all you need to do is something like this from the PHP script in question

```
exec("someplayer.exe sound.mp3");
```

Comment: is this playing on people who visited my website? how about it's only playing on my server? is it posibble?

Comment: This will only play on the server as it is being run by PHP which is running on your server

Answer (score 1):

It depends of your code.
Assuming you already have a javascript audio player,
you can maybe use an ajax call for the database insertion and play a sound when it's done.